# Openssl cannot interpret non-English Character

Tags: windows, openssl

I am using windows openssl version 3.0.1 14. The issue is when the file name has non-English character, it failed to encrypt the file with below error:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop>openssl aes-256-cbc -e -salt -in "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test\试试.txt" -out "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test\ENCRYPTING.txt" -k 12230000000000000000000000000000 -iv F1230000000000000000000000000000
Can't open "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test\??.txt" for reading, Invalid argument
B8280000:error:8000007B:system library:BIO_new_file:Unknown error:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Users\lishi\Desktop\test\??.txt, rb)
B8280000:error:10080002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:77:
```

The terminal I use is Windows command prompt, I verified that this Chinese file can be opened successfully in cmd using issuing:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop>notepad C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test\试试.txt
```

Any configuration things I need to do in openssl side to support utf8?

Comment: I suspect [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261746/openssl-converting-chars-to-utf-8-literals) is your problem since your command to generate the certificate does not have `-utf8` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the MinGW binaries, this may be related to the automatic conversion of UTF-8 on Windows platforms.

OpenSSL provides an environment variable to deal with this.
From the manual...

> OPENSSL_WIN32_UTF8

> If set, then UI_OpenSSL(3) returns UTF-8 encoded strings, rather than ones encoded in the current code page, and the openssl(1) program also transcodes the command-line parameters from the current code page to UTF-8. This environment variable is only checked on Microsoft Windows platforms.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/openssl-env.html

Comment: Thanks, so, basically, I need to add OPENSSL_WIN32_UTF8 = 1 to the Windows system environment variable, right?

Comment: Yes, give that a try. If that doesn't work you could also try adding the -utf8 argument to the command line.