# Configuring Stunnel on windows - TLS error for certificate

Tags: windows, stunnel

I can't get Stunnel (5.69) to start on Windows 2022 server. I have a Sectigo certificate with full chain that is PEM-encoded but I get this error:

```
Server is down
[ ] Initializing inetd mode configuration
[ ] Running on Windows 6.2
[.] Reading configuration from file C:\Program Files (x86)\stunnel\config\stunnel.conf
[.] UTF-8 byte order mark detected
[.] FIPS mode disabled
[ ] Compression disabled
[ ] No PRNG seeding was required
[ ] Initializing service [CAIRLAB_SERVER_PROD]
[ ] stunnel default security level set: 2
[ ] Ciphers: HIGH:!aNULL:!SSLv2:!DH:!kDHEPSK
[ ] TLSv1.3 ciphersuites: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
[ ] TLS options: 0x2100000 (+0x0, -0x0)
[ ] Session resumption enabled
[ ] Loading certificate from file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\stunnel\config\my_fancy.cer"
[!] error queue: ssl/ssl_rsa.c:448: error:0A080002:SSL routines::system lib
[!] error queue: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:300: error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib
[!] SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:297: error:8000007B:system library::Unknown error
[!] Service [CAIRLAB_SERVER_PROD]: Failed to initialize TLS context
[!] Configuration failed
[ ] Deallocating temporary section defaults
[ ] Deallocating section [CAIRLAB_SERVER_PROD]
```

I get the exact same error when changing the path so I assume that the *unknown error* is Stunnel not finding the file. The cer-file is located in the config-folder together with the key-file.

Comment: I found `error:8000007B` here: https://superuser.com/questions/1706984/openssl-cannot-interpret-non-english-character, which was a UTF-8 encoding error, did you have any non-english characters in the file path? Try and check the cert contents using the same openssl that stunnel uses, like: `openssl x509 -inform PERM -in filename.pem -text`

Comment: Can't get the info command to run. The certificate was generated prior signing with: `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private_server.key -out pub_server.csr` I assume that I need this in x509 format. The path is standard `Program (x86)...` folder - not sure that this a problem. I find it weird that despite change the file name to a non-existing file path the error is unchanged.

Comment: sorry, `PERM` should have been `PEM` - it's still worth testing to make sure openssl likes it (if you combined your certs in notepad or whatever, the encoding might have changed). Since bad paths give the same error, can you add your `stunnel.conf` contents to your question? For example, it looks like the format should be `cert = C:\Program Files (x86)\stunnel\my_fancy.cer` with no quotes

Comment: Thank you, the error were the `"` marks. The `openssl x509 -inform PEM -in stunnel.pem -text` works like a charm with no errors and everything seems to make sense.

Now I have `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file: crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:405: error:05800074:x509 certificate routines::key values mismatch` - I guess this is some sort of progress.

Comment: How did you combine your key and certs after signing? Take a look through some of the answers here for solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191463/ssl-error0b080074x509-certificate-routinesx509-check-private-keykey-values